# Windows 10 - Taskbar - Add item to context menu for each program

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry, shell-extensions

I need a context menu entry for each program in the taskbar. Want to add an entry which immediately terminates (UNIX/Linux-like signal SIGKILL) the process. There a lot of questions on this site, how it's done for the explorer or desktop. But is it also possible to add such an option to the context menu of the taskbar?

[image: Illustration]

To clarify the question, according to my comments:

*The current problem:*

I have a program (not Firefox) which randomly crashes. The program is in fullscreen mode. But if I want to close the window of the program with **Exit window**, it takes a long time that Windows kill the program. When I try to open the Task Manager the program immediately grabs the user input and I have no chance to interact with the Task Manager. So my solution was to add a context menu item in the taskbar to quit the task of the program. According to a user comment, I test the option "Always on top" in the Task Manager. Didn't know that. But I haven't tried it yet. I'm also interested for further projects, if there is a function in **WINAPI** or **Windows Registry** to add an item.

*To avoid down-votes:*

I'm not interested to hack Windows or the application. Solutions with code injection are taboo for me. Want a clean solution, if even possible. I want improve my Windows version. Adding also some additional information (process information) in the context menu.

Have currently found [this (Registering shell extension handlers)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/reg-shell-exts).
Has anybody used this before? I think it's sound promising.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no API to add a custom context menu to the Taskbar button of any app that you do not control.  Apps have to add their own menu items via available Taskbar APIs.  To do what you are asking would require injecting code into every running process that displays a Taskbar button

Comment: [ICustomDestinationList::AddUserTasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-icustomdestinationlist-addusertasks). Shoving that into other processes is something you'll have to figure out.

Comment: One problem I see is that one program listed in the taskbar may have several instances running, i.e. several processes. Also, a single instance may consist of several different processes. For example, some programs consist of a launcher process and a main process. You have no way of knowing which processes to kill, since the programs do not provide this information.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Okay, thats's a good point. But I would be happy when the UI thread is killed. The problem: I have a buggy program which crashes in fullscreen and grabs the user input. I can open the Windows task manager, but when I try to click on the task manager, the buggy program immediately grabs all user inputs. I want this option to get the control back from the OS. Only the context menu is working but it takes a long time until Windows "kick" the program.

Comment: @krjdev: How are you leaving full-screen? ALT-TAB may not work reliably, you should maybe try ALT-CTRL-DELETE (ALT-STRG-ENTF on German keyboard) or CTRL-SHIFT-ESC, since these key combinations are protected by the operating system and should not allow interference from other programs.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: With CTRL-ALT-DEL (or STRG-ALT-ENTF on my keyboard) I can open the task manager. I shortly see the task manager, but then the crashed program goes back to the top. I have no chance to interact with the task manager, to select the program and kill the program (Task beenden). That's the problem.

Comment: @krjdev: Sounds like an operating system bug if it doesn't allow you to reliably kill a process. Is the affected process only "buggy" or is it possibly maliciously trying to prevent itself from being killed?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Maliciously :) I think it's  maybe a protection to prevent to open the debugger. Okay, the program which doesn't close is the game Diablo 3. :)

Comment: @krjdev: Maybe one of these links will help? [1](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/force-quit-full-screen-program-game-windows-10) [2](https://superuser.com/questions/632207/terminate-program-that-has-taken-over-the-screen) [3](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/forcefully-close-full-screen-application-or-game-with-superf4/)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: I will read and try your links. Thanks. But I'm also want to solve it for my own.

Comment: @krjdev: Here is [another link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170425-00/?p=96035) that looks interesting. It is a page written by a Microsoft Blogger.

Comment: @krjdev: Do you also have the problem with "Always on top" enabled in the task manager? (Not sure what it is called in German, probably something like "immer im Vordergrund" or something like that).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Okay, enabled. It's called "Immer im Vordergrund". Nice to learn something new. I will give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209960/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-krjdev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to extend this menu like that. Applications can customize the top of the menu with [ICustomDestinationList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-icustomdestinationlist-addusertasks) but there is no way to add entries for all applications.

For a personal use project, you could inject a .dll in the taskbar instance of Explorer.exe and add your item after figuring out the address of the function where the menu is created. This address can of course change after you upgrade Windows so it is not a very generic solution. Using the public symbols might help but you still have to expect it to break from time to time when Microsoft changes part of their taskbar code.

Comment: What about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/shell/reg-shell-exts)? Sounds promising for me, but not tried it yet. My intention is a extension of the shell.

Comment: @krjdev - this is just the general mechanism for extending the Shell. The list of Shell extensions type is fixed, there's nothing that can help you solve your problem. Everything available about the new taskbar from Windows 7 is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions well actually if you read it carefully, there may be something that could help (but different than your original request)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to change code in explorer.exe, because you can close a program by doing the keyboard shortcut: Alt + F4.

Comment: You have to click on the program first though.